# Perl Error Handling for Win32::ODBC

Tags: sql-server, windows, perl

I am having a heck of a time with some error catching for some SQL statements.

A little background:
A previous co-worker (unfortunately passed away) wrote a perl module that has all kinds of goodies in it. A logging function, an Archiving function, an FTP function...all kinds of awesome stuff.

He also wrote the script I am having problems with.

Anyway, part of the logging function looks for a specific variable to be set, if it is, it marks the log with an error.

Here is part of the function that is used in the live code:

```
$dbOR = new Win32::ODBC($DNSORDERS) or $strNewError = 1;
Logger("Connect to $dbOR", "CANT CONNECT TO $dbOR", $strNewError, $strErrorFile);
```

In the above case, if the connection fails, `$strNewError` gets set to a value of 1. Once this is set, any other portions of the script looking to see if an error occurred before they process something, will not process it if there is an error found.

That also causes the error log to print the `"CANT..."` portion of that logger function into the log file. If it does connect, it prints the `"Connect..."` portion in the log file.

Now here is my problem:

I have this piece of code, that is updating some values after doing some processing (to prevent the re-processing of data if the script is run again).

```
$strSQLNotNull  = "UPDATE WHTransfers ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "SET Complete = 1 ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "WHERE Complete IS NULL ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "AND (((ProcessDate IS NULL OR ProcessDate <= GETDATE()) ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "AND [DeptNum] = $strDEPTNUM ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "AND [ToStore] = $strTOSTORE ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "AND [FromStore] = $strFROMSTORE) ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "OR [ActQty] = 0)";

$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull);

#Logger("Marked Transfer $strFileName as Completed" ,"UNABLE TO MARK $strFileName AS COMPLETED", $strNewError, $strErrorFile);
```

Now, I tested the code and it does do the update to the database fields. If I add a `$strNewError = 1` onto the end of the `$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull);` it throws the error and sets `$strNewError = 1`, regardless of whether it executes correctly or not (I verified it flagged the error even though it did the update).

Obviously this is causing problems, as it causes the remainder of the script to think an error occurred (which it has checks for). When an error is detected, the script basically stops processing.

Any ideas on how I can get a true error checking to work with the above portion? I would love any suggestions on how to incorporate the existing error checking/logger function, to properly catch an execute error.

If you need any other information, please ask and I will provide what I can.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `$dbOR->Sql` gets set in [this subroutine](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-ODBC-0.035/ODBC.pm#L645):

```
sub updateResults{
    my ($self, $Error, @Results) = @_;

    undef %{$self->{'field'}};

    ClearError($self);
    if ($Error){
        SetError($self, $Results[0], $Results[1]);
        return ($Error);
    }

    @{$self->{'fnames'}} = @Results;

    foreach (0..$#{$self->{'fnames'}}){
        s/ +$//;
        $self->{'field'}->{${$self->{'fnames'}}[$_]} = $_;
    }
    return undef;
}
```

That is, it returns `undef` if there were no errors, and returns `$Error` if there was an error.

Now, you say:

> If I add a `$strNewError = 1` onto the end of the `$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull);` ...

It is not at all clear what that sentence means (***always*** err on the side of showing relevant code instead of writing ambiguous prose), but if you are doing:

```
$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull) or $strNewError = 1;
```

that will set `$strNewError` to `1` *only if* there was no error.

Incidentally,

```
$strSQLNotNull .= "WHERE Complete IS NULL ";
$strSQLNotNull .= "AND (((ProcessDate IS NULL ... );
```

as well as `$strNewError = 1` indicate issues with overall code quality.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, this code is not exactly what I would call 'good'. I am having to go back through and fix a lot of issues in his scripts.

The reason I was doing `$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull) or $strNewError = 1;` was because that is how all of his scripts are set up. Most of them, such as php, when it does a SQL statement execution, adding that new error portion at the end, instead of `or die` trips the flag in his Logging function.

I see why he completely left out the error checking that integrates with his logging function....because it was more work than he wanted to bother with.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Have you considered `$dbOR ->Sql($strSQLNotNull) and $strNewError = 1;`? Or, actually doing something with the error if one is returned?

Comment: Hi Sinan,

Basically in almost all of his code, any time he does any kind of actions that have a possiblility to fail, he has the `or $strNewError = 1` on it. 

Such as: 
`$dbOR = new Win32::ODBC($DNSORDERS) or $strNewError = 1;`
`Logger("Connect to $dbOR" ,"CANT CONNECT TO $dbOR", $strNewError, $strErrorFile);`

If the connection works/is opened, $strNewError does not get set to a value of 1. If it fails to open the connection, it sets $strNewError to a value of 1. And writes to the log. Then, where he goes to do something, he starts off with `if(!$strErrorFlag){ do some code; }`.